# How to pass canvas imageData to emscripten c++ program without copying it?

Tags: javascript, c++, canvas, emscripten, asm.js

I have Image data of the canvas:

```
myImage = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, 640, 480);
```

I figured out, that i can create new `Uint8Array` and use `set()` to copy imagedata. This is working example:

```
var numBytes = width * height * 4;
var ptr= Module._malloc(numBytes);
var heapBytes= new Uint8Array(Module.HEAPU8.buffer, ptr, numBytes);
heapBytes.set(new Uint8Array(myImage.data));
_processImage(heapBytes.byteOffset, width, height);
myImage.data.set(heapBytes);
```

But, unfortunately every `.set()` operation is far more slower than processing image, and the code above is slower than JS implementation!

So, I want to process image without copying it. I can successfuly read and write the data directly to the heap this way:

```
Module.HEAPU8.set(myImage.data, myImage.data.byteOffset);
_processImage(myImage.data.byteOffset, width, height);
myImage.data.set(new Uint8ClampedArray(Module.HEAPU8.buffer , myImage.data.byteOffset , numBytes));
```

It's faster, but still the first `.set()` takes 17ms to execute.

The c++ function prototype is:

```
extern "C" {

    int processImage(unsigned char *buffer, int width, int height)
    {
    }

}
```

Is there any way to pass the array to C++ without using `set()`? Just telling the c++ where the data is in memory, and allow to modify it?

Comment: What browser/OS/system specs is this running on? 17ms is a bit long for copying a 640x480 image in memory...

Comment: Chrome 46 / Windows 7 64bit / Xeon E31235 @ 3.20 GHz / 8 GB. On the firefox set() is much more faster, but the emcescript asm.js is working slower...

Answer (score 2):

> Just telling the c++ where the data is in memory, and allow to modify it?

As of v1.34.12, Emscripten has a [SPLIT_MEMORY](https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/blob/1.35.14/src/settings.js#L595) option, where you can tell Emscripten to use an existing buffer as part of its memory space that is split up into evenly sized chunks

You could, for example, get the buffer from the canvas

```
var existingBuffer = myImage.data.buffer;
var bufferSize = existingBuffer.byteLength; // Must be equal to SPLIT_MEMORY
```

and then, modifying the example from the [explanation of split memory](https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/wiki/Split-Memory#allocating-a-chunk-with-existing-data), tell Emscripten to use this buffer as part of its memory space

```
var chunkIndex = 2; // For example
allocateSplitChunk(chunkIndex, existingBuffer);
```

and then pass a pointer to the chunk to your C++ function.

```
var pointerToImageInGlobalMemorySpace = chunkIndex * bufferSize;
_processImage(pointerToImageInGlobalMemorySpace, width, height);
```

*However* there are problems and limitations

- The Emscripten memory space must be split into chunks exactly the size of the canvas image data buffer.
- There are apparently [serious performance implications](https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/wiki/Split-Memory#performance) for all of the Emscripten-compiled code, which might make this perform worse than your original code.